# Overloading copy constructor with delete and then calling the default constructor of a subclass in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to disable or rather delete the copy constructor of the parent class Card with the line `Card(const Card&) = delete;`

When I call `Quartz* qu = new Quartz();` in the main i get the error that the default constructor is deleted? I find this confusing since I did not think I was defining a default constructor in Card but rather an overload of the copy constructor. Any explanations or workarounds for this much appreciated.

```
class Card {
public:

    Card(const Card&) = delete;

};

class Quartz : public Card {
public:
    Quartz() = default;


};

int main() {

    Quartz* qu = new Quartz();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default  constructor is only implicitly  defined if the class has no other constructors. Since you defined a copy constructor, you now need to explicitly define default  one, too.